# ORACLE: PIVOT table for Dynamic data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table 
    select * from xx_test

[image]

I need a query to get the output as below

[image]

I tried the below query

```
SELECT
    PROJECT,
    TASK,
    PROJ_NAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'DEC-16' THEN cost END) AS DEC_16,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'JAN-17' THEN cost END) AS JAN_17    
FROM    xx_test
GROUP BY PROJECT,
    TASK,
    PROJ_NAME
```

It seems to give the desired output but unfortunately, the table data will be populated based on the periods given in my report parameters(i.e., DEC-16, JAN-17 will not be same all the time).

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: will you always pass two parameters? or it can be more? I just want to know that number of columns that you want into the desired result will be always 5?

Comment: @Tejash the period is a from/to parameter in the report. If I pass Dec-16(as from) and Mar-17(as To) parameters the period column will have DEC-16,JAN-17,FEB-17 and Mar-17. So the answer is No, I'll not have 5 columns always in the result. The no.of columns will be dynamic, depends on the PERIOD FROM/PERIOD TO values.

Comment: Then you must go with the dynamic query as oracle SQL query do not allow the dynamic number of columns.

Comment: I am not good at writing dynamic queries, could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a dynamic pivot natively in the database, but Anton from AMIS did the next best thing with a PLSQL utility to provide it

https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/